# Voiceover heading rotor collectionView navigation

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility, voiceover

I'm trying to turn on accesibillity on iOS. I've set `Static Text, User Interaction Enabled` and `Header`. When i trying navigate by collectionview cell elements everything is read, also system correcly reading headers, BUT navigation is not working as espected. After touching screen on enabled voiceover rotor heading mode it is NOT skipping to only headers text

Should i enable something more?

[image: storyboard]

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure we're on the same page:

You have "headings" turned on in Settings > Accessibility > Voiceover > Rotor?

[image]

And then in your app, you change your Rotor to "Headings"?

[image]

And then when you swipe up/down, it won't navigate to the headings?  Can you test it in the Clock app to make sure headings work in general for you?  Go to the "Alarm" tab and enable heading navigation in the rotor then swipe up/down.  Here's what I get:

My focus is on "Alarm" at the top and the VoiceOver captioning panel at the bottom says "Alarm, Heading".

[image]

If I swipe down, it goes to the "sleep" heading:

[image]

The next swipe down goes to the "Other" heading:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes i have turned on headings in voiceover settings. In system app it's working, in my app unfortunately not

Comment: Ok, at least we have a common baseline to work from.  Can you try creating three headings? One with your original, one with "static text" turned off, and one with "user interaction enabled" turned off. Just want to see if those other settings are affecting the "heading-ness" of the element.

Comment: It's weird, but when i unselected all traits nothing change. It's keep reading all of the content. I dont have any accesibility code in this class or collection view cell.

Comment: Even when i did experiment you suggest, its also nothing change

Comment: Any ideas about this issue?

Comment: *"It's weird, but when i unselected all traits nothing change"*.  That sounds like your changes are not being picked up. Like stuff was recompiled but not deployed correctly. I would again do what I suggested and create three types of headings with those various traits set but change the text of the headings to make sure you're picking up your changes.

Comment: I checked traits and heading is read only in right place, but navigation on rotator "headings" keeps reading all content

Comment: I also set accessibilityContainerType = .semanticGroup on collectionview. If i picked containers on rotor its navigating well, but not on headings in cells in CV